# "Sticky" Excel Pivot Table Slicers

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to make my Pivot Table's slicers be "sticky" (where they stay in the screen even when you scroll).

I found [an article](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4381-excel-slicer-move-with-scroll.html) that shows how to do it based on the cell that was selected but that's not helpful if I use the scrollbar...
This is the code that I have (this is based on some code that was shared in [this comment](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4381-excel-slicer-move-with-scroll.html#comment-11596))

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ShF As Shape
    Dim ShM As Shape
    'specify a slicer
    Set ShF = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Response3")
    Set ShM = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Response2")
    'change position of the slicer
    With Windows(1).VisibleRange.Cells(1, 1)
        ShF.Top = .Top + 55
        ShM.Top = .Top + 155
    End With
End Sub
```

I also looked at [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/scrollheight-scrollleft-scrolltop-scrollwidth-properties-example) that showed how to use the scrollbar data, but that only gave me the "Object required" error...
With the documentation I have this code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ShF As Shape
    Dim ShM As Shape
    'specify a slicer
    Set ShF = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Response3")
    Set ShM = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Response2")
    'change position of the slicer
    ShF.Top = MultiPage1.Pages(1).ScrollTop + 55
    ShM.Top = MultiPage1.Pages(1).ScrollTop + 155
End Sub
```

Can someone please help me with this?

How can I make my slicers stay still even when scrolling (this can be still only in the vertical direction, meaning you can scroll vertically but the slicers don't move vertically)?

Comment: Won't freeze pane do?

Comment: I tried freeze pane, but I don't know really how to use it, and it doesn't seem to freeze the spots I want... or in the way that I want...

Comment: If your slicers are aligned then you freeze horizontally at a row below the slicers. Then you can scroll with slicers remaining in view.

Comment: I have (and want) my slicers off to the right side aligned horizontally with each other...

Comment: What happens if you then freeze at the row  below those?

Comment: That makes the Pivot Table and Pivot Chart next to the slicers stay as well...